# React.js won't render in my Codepen

Tags: javascript, reactjs, codepen

I'm trying to create a counter and I can't get what's in the render to show on the page.

Here is my code in JS from Codepen (with React and ReactDOM added in external JS)

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
    };
    this.flash = "";
    this.count = 0;
  }

  componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    var newValue = nextProps.count;
    if (this.count !== newValue) {
      this.flash = this.flash === "flash1" ? "flash2" : "flash1";
    }
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <div id="counter">
        <button>+</button>
        <button>-</button>
        <div id="count" className={this.flash}>
          {this.count}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  };
}


ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('countContainer'));
```

I can see in my JS code that normally the  should be the color brown in my Codepen, so I'm obviously missing something (it's currently yellow).

In my HTML I have the following

```
<div id="countContainer">
</div>
```

Note: I'm not done with the code in regards to what it should be able to do in the end. I figured I should try and get it to render on the page before I continue.

My codepen is:  [URL](http://%20codepen.io/sbcreates/pen/qVxjNY?editors=1010)

Comment: Can you share the link of your codepen

Comment: sure, it's https://codepen.io/sbcreates/pen/qVxjNY?editors=1010

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried this and got an error at the line where the first JSX tag is inside render().  I fixed it by adding the Babel preprocessor in addition to React and ReactDOM.

Comment: Hmm, for me it doesn't change anything when I change the preprocessor to Babel.

Comment: Change line 1 from Component back to React.Component on your Codepen.  You have it as "Component" right now so there's a different error occurring due to that.  It worked perfectly for me when I copied and pasted your code as it is in the question.

Comment: This is and should be the accepted answer. Including the external CDN scripts for React and ReactDOM with Babel as the preprocessor answers OP.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this code to get the counter working with both increment and decrement count .

```
class Counter extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      count :0
    };
    this.increment=this.increment.bind(this);
    this.decrement=this.decrement.bind(this);
  }
increment(){
  this.setState({count:this.state.count+1});
}
decrement(){
  this.setState({count:this.state.count-1});
}
  render () {
    return (
      <div id="counter">
        <button onClick={this.increment}>+</button>
        <button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button>
        <div>
          {this.state.count}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}


ReactDOM.render(<Counter />, document.getElementById('countContainer'));
```

just define the functions and trigger them using onClick().

Here is the working counter in codepen with your code, modified it a bit to make it work. https://codepen.io/coderakki/pen/QOQqMP?editors=0010

Update : also, you need to define count within the state of your component .